# Function returning a different datatype

Tags: .net, vb.net, types, type-conversion

I just come across the following snippet:

```
Public Function Checked() As Boolean
      Return applyChange 'This is a string!
End Function
```

What's going on here? How can a function with return type `Boolean` actually return a `string`? I'm assuming there's some implicit conversion going on here, which I'd rather not have. Am I missing a compilation option?

This is .NET 1.0.

Comment: Have you tried using `Option Strict`?

Comment: It appears that I hadn't.  With it being .net 1 its not set to on as default.  As soon as I've done this I got a tonne of compiler errors :-)

Comment: +1 A great question. This is why people hate VB.NET: they don't know how to use it. Like everything else, it helpfully enables you to shoot yourself in the foot. Doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the *language*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You're missing the [`Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) compilation option.** You'll find it in your project's Properties window, under the "Compile" tab. With it turned on, you get the following error:

[image: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Boolean'.]

And I suggest turning this option on **immediately** and fixing all resulting compilation errors. Converting from a `String` to a `Boolean` is a risky proposition. In the event that `applyChange` is actually set to a string like "Hello" (instead of "True" or "False"), you'll get the following **run-time** error:

> Conversion from string "Hello" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: Alternatively, put "Option Strict On" in the beginning of the source file(s). It is especially useful when working with legacy code that was never compiled with Option Strict On.

Comment: You could definitely put it in the source file. But I find that to be error prone, since I rarely remember to add it to new source files. If it's set as a compiler option, it applies globally. Back in the bad old days with VB 6, the "compiler" option for Option Explicit literally just added this line to the top of the file, but it doesn't work that way anymore with VB.NET—they are actual compiler settings. What makes more sense would be turning it on globally, and then selectively turning it *off* for certain legacy source code files.